# $scope's method called via ng-click: executed twice by IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-click

In my controller:

```js
$scope.homeAction = function() {
  console.log("HomeAction");
};
```

In my view:

```xml
<button ng-click="homeAction()">call homeAction()</button>
```

When clicking the button, the method gets executed as expected by Chrome and Firefox, but IE executes it twice. Any idea why?

Here is a plunker that reproduces the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/pedZKjIVGDAYfMl0ZphJ.

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir Tested with IE 11.

Comment: Executes only once on IE 11

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir Weird! Just tried on https://www.browserstack.com/, still reproducing...

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2885

Comment: Yup even I also reproduces the same. Shocking.

Comment: add <form novalidate></form> and check whether it is working twice or once

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add `type="button"`to your button and it should be fixed. Default behaviour is submit and apparently that messes with your code.

```
<ion-view title="Home">

  <ion-content padding="true">
    <button type="button" ng-click="homeAction()" class="button button-block button-positive">call homeAction()</button>
  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be related to the `<button>` event handling on Internet Explorer. Clicking it dispatches 2 events : `MouseEvent` and `PointerEvent` which explains why `homeAction` is called twice.

The easiest solution would be to change the `<button>` element to another DOM element (i.e. `<a>` or `<span>`)

Updated version using an `<a>` element http://plnkr.co/edit/Nn8CF7TnDKqsJA3unsp6

Another solution would be to verify which type of Event is dispatched and only allow `MouseEvents`. You can do this by passing the $event on your `HomeAction` and check the existence of the `pointerType` property (which is only available on TouchEvents). An example on plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/RmVHT1Pf2IeCNdmDH51T

```
$scope.homeAction = function($event) {
    if ($event.originalEvent.pointerType) {
      //PointerEvent, don't do anything
      return;
    }

    console.log("HomeAction");
};
```