# ng-click fired multiple times after compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-scope, angularjs-compile

I have read many SO answer but couldn't resolve the problem.

I have a `Javascript function` that create `HTML` element like `document.createElement(...)`

This is a part of that function :

```
var div=document.getElementById(params.wrapper);
div.setAttribute("ng-controller","ProjectController");

var button = document.createElement('button');
button.setAttribute('id','btn-view-users-' + params.id);
button.className='button-manage-user';
button.setAttribute('ng-click','hello()');
div.appendChild(button);
```

This function is called at the start of the application and create many rows so when the page is loaded the HTML generated by the function look like this : (*this sample code is simplified to be more comprehensible*)

```
<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper ng-scope" ng-controller="ProjectController">
    <button id="btn-view-users-310" class="button-manage-user" ng-click="hello()">Manage Users</button>
    <button id="btn-view-users-311" class="button-manage-user" ng-click="hello()">Manage Users</button>
    <button id="btn-view-users-312" class="button-manage-user" ng-click="hello()">Manage Users</button>
    <button id="btn-view-users-313" class="button-manage-user" ng-click="hello()">Manage Users</button>
</div>
```

The Angular controller :

```
app.controller('ProjectController',
    ['$scope', '$http',
        function($scope, $http) {
             $scope.hello = function(){
                console.log("hello")
             }
        }
    ]
)
```

At the end of the function when all elements are created I compile with :

```
var content = $(".wrapper");
angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
    var scope = angular.element(content).scope();
    $compile(content)(scope);
    console.log("#compile")//log appears in the console 10 times if 10 elements are created.
});
```

**But when I click on the button the "hello" is fired many times !**

If I have **10 elements** on the page and click on the **first** element it is fire **10 times**, if I click on the **second** element it is fired **9 times** and so on..

I have tried to move the `ng-controller` declaration inside the button `button.setAttribute("ng-controller","ProjectController");` Or even in the `<body>` tag  but I still get the same behavior.

Thanks for you help

Comment: Google Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit)

Comment: OK, because I met such a behavior too, but only with IE. In case of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32090543/1225328

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you are compiling the `controller` div, Which will do compile `ng-controller="ProjectController"` directive and will register instance of your  `ProjectController` as many times you compile the div.

You should do `$compile(content.contents())(scope);` instead of compiling whole controller element.

But `compile` element should have only one root element like in your case you can not do that, because element which you wanted to compile should have exact one root element. Other should be child element of that root.

Comment: Actually there is more div imbricated in my code. The example I gave is simplified. What you are saying is  I should compile the ng-controller definition child div?

Comment: @Lorenzo yes..but in your you need to change bit structure.. do look at edit

Comment: I cannot post the entire code its a way to big! Could you explain where I'm supposed to declare the ´ng-controller´ and which part I am supposed to ´compile´. Should I complie the part where the ng-controller is declared ? Could you provide a small example please ? If compile the ng-controller's child div the ng-click is not firing... Thank you

Comment: @Lorenzo can I know when you are calling the the code by which you are compiling element..

Comment: Inside the function that create the elements. At the end of the function. And this function is called many times... it might be the problem

Comment: Thanks for you help you get me on the right direction. Problem is solved!

Comment: @Lorenzo Glad to help you..basically you need to compile `ng-controller` once...other time you just need to compile its child..