# Ghost click triggers button event after I touch another button - Ionic Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an app that has been built with Cordova and Ionic. The app has an  html template that shows two lists. I can add, modify and delete elements in the two lists.

The problem is, sometimes, when I click a button (any button) or when I select a list item, the app triggers another button's click event (or a list item click event). This behavior seems to be random, so I haven't been able to determine why it happens.

One thing that I have noticed is that the ghost click only happens on a button or list item that is being shown on the screen.

Can anyone provide any guidance about why is this happening or how to prevent this behavior?

Here is part of the code of the html view:

```html
<button class="fab-button" ng-click='vm.continuar("reclamo.firma")'>
    <i class="ion-android-arrow-forward" style="color: white; font-size: 30px;"></i>
</button>

<ion-content>
    <h2>Datos del Tercero y Daño</h2>
    <form name='form' novalidate class="css-form">

        <!-- 
            ... a lot of code
         -->        

        <div class="row" style='padding-top: 5px;' ng-class='{"fila-par": !$even}' ng-repeat="foto in terceroMostrado.fotosUris track by $index">
            <div class="col">
                <img ng-if="$index < 5" ng-src="{{foto.uri}}" width='60%' ng-click='vm.verFotoEnGrande(foto.uri, $index + 1)'></img>
                <span ng-if="$index >= 5" class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click='vm.verFotoEnGrande(foto.uri, $index + 1)'>(Ver foto {{$index + 1}})</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <span class='linea1'>Foto: {{$index + 1}}</span>
                <br />
                <span class='linea2'>Tomada: {{foto.fechaYHora.toString('dd-MMM-yyyy h:mmtt')}}</span>
                <br />
                <a class="button button-clear button-assertive" style='padding-left:0px; display:inline' ng-click='vm.eliminarFoto($index)'>
                    Eliminar Foto {{$index + 1}}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row linea1">
            <div ng-show='terceroMostradoIndice == -1' class="col">
                <!-- THIS BUTTON CAUSES A GHOST CLICK and also is triggered by a ghost clicked -->
                <input type='button' class='button button-calm' value='Agregar Tercero' ng-click='vm.agregarTercero()' data-tap-disabled="true"/>
            </div>
            <div ng-show='terceroMostradoIndice != -1' class="col">
                <!-- THIS BUTTON CAUSES A GHOST CLICK and also is triggered by a ghost clicked -->
                <input type='button' class='button button-calm' value='Guardar Modificaciones' ng-click='vm.guardarTercero()' data-tap-disabled="true"/>
            </div>
            <div ng-show='terceroMostradoIndice != -1' class="col">
                <!-- THIS BUTTON CAUSES A GHOST CLICK and also is triggered by a ghost clicked -->
                <input type='button' class='button button-outline button-calm' value='Descartar Modificaciones' ng-click='vm.descartarModificaciones()' data-tap-disabled="true"/>
            </div>
            <div ng-show='terceroMostradoIndice != -1' class="col">
                <!-- THIS BUTTON CAUSES A GHOST CLICK -->
                <input type='button' class='button button-outline button-calm' value='Eliminar Tercero' ng-click='vm.eliminarTercero()' data-tap-disabled="true"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h3>Listado de Terceros</h3>

        <!-- Lista de Terceros -->
        <div class="row linea1">
            <div class="col">
                Nombre
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                Identificación
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                Fotos
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                Mostrando
            </div>
        </div>
        <ion-list id="lista-terceros">
            <!-- Hay que usar ng-repeat, porque con collection-repeat, el form no hace el scroll en la tablet. -->
            <!-- THIS LIST ITEM IS SELECTED BY A GHOST CLICK -->
            <ion-item ng-click='vm.editarTercero($index)' ng-repeat="t in tercero track by $index"  data-tap-disabled="true">
                <div class="row linea2">
                    <div class="col" style='text-transform: uppercase;'>
                        {{t.nombre}} 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col" style='text-transform: uppercase;'>
                        {{t.identificacion}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col" style='text-transform: uppercase;'>
                        {{t.fotosUris ? t.fotosUris.length : 0}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <i class='ion-checkmark-circled check-lista' ng-show='($index == terceroMostradoIndice)'></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </form>

</ion-content>
```

Here is part of the code of the controller:

```js
function ReclamoDetalleTerceroController($ionicModal, $ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup, $scope, $state, $stateParams, fotosFactory, reclamoDetalleFactory, reclamosFactory, reclamosDbFactory, toastr) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.agregarTercero = agregarTercero;
    vm.descartarModificaciones = descartarModificaciones;
    vm.editarTercero = editarTercero;
    vm.eliminarTercero = eliminarTercero;
    vm.guardarTercero = guardarTercero;

    /*
      Esta variable contiene los detalles del tercero que se muestra en el template.
      Es importante tener esta variable aparte para mostrar los datos porque así el usuario puede descartar los cambios realizados.
    */
    $scope.terceroMostrado = {};
    $scope.terceroMostradoIndice = -1;
    // Esta variable contiene la lista de todos los terceros creados.
    $scope.tercero = [];

    var corriendoEnBrowser = window.cordova? false : true;

    $ionicPlatform.ready(activar);

    function activar() {
      vm.reclamo = reclamoDetalleFactory.obtenerObjeto($stateParams.id).reclamo;
      $scope.tercero = reclamoDetalleFactory.obtenerObjeto($stateParams.id).tercero;

      $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('app/fotos/ver-foto-modal.html', {
        scope: $scope, // Con esto, el modal tiene acceso al parent scope; o sea, a las variables de este controlador.
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
      }).then(function(modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
      });
      //Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
      $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $scope.modal.remove();
      });
    }

    function agregarTercero() {
      console.log('agregarTercero()');
      if (validarTercero()) {
        var nuevoTercero = {};
        copiarValoresTercero($scope.terceroMostrado, nuevoTercero)
        $scope.tercero.push(nuevoTercero);
        console.log('agregarTercero() nuevoTercero.kms: ' + nuevoTercero.kms);
        limpiarCampos();
        toastr.success('Tercero agregado con éxito.', 'Éxito');
      }
    }

    function copiarValoresTercero(origen, destino) {
      destino.anio = origen.anio;
      destino.color = origen.color;
      destino.daniosVehiculo = origen.daniosVehiculo;
      destino.email = origen.email;
      destino.fueTrasladadoEnGrua = origen.fueTrasladadoEnGrua;
      destino.identificacion = origen.identificacion;
      destino.kms = origen.kms;
      destino.lesionado = origen.lesionado;
      destino.lugarTraslado = origen.lugarTraslado;
      destino.marca = origen.marca;
      destino.modelo = origen.modelo;
      //noHayTercero: destino.noHayTercero, // Este campo no va.
      destino.nombre = origen.nombre;
      destino.nombreAseguradora = origen.nombreAseguradora;
      destino.numeroPoliza = origen.numeroPoliza;
      destino.placa = origen.placa;
      destino.sucursalPreferida = origen.sucursalPreferida;
      destino.tallerPreferido = origen.tallerPreferido;
      destino.telOCelular = origen.telOCelular;
      /*
        Estamos copiando la referencia del arreglo, así que las fotos que se tomen se pasarán automáticamente aunque el usuario no guarde los cambios
        del tercero. Lo hacemos así porque las fotos de todos modos quedarán guardadas en el dispositivo, aunque el usuario no guarde los cambios
        del tercero.
      */
      destino.fotosUris = origen.fotosUris;
    }

    function descartarModificaciones() {
      var titulo = 
      $ionicPopup.show({
        title: '¿Deseas descartar los cambios realizados al tercero ' + $scope.tercero[$scope.terceroMostradoIndice].nombre.toUpperCase() + ' con identificación ' + $scope.tercero[$scope.terceroMostradoIndice].identificacion.toUpperCase() + '?',
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Sí',
            onTap: function(e) {
              toastr.info('No se realizaron modificaciones.', 'Sin cambios');
              limpiarCampos();
            }
          },
          {
            text: '<b>No</b>',
            type: 'button-positive',
            onTap: function(e) {
              // No pasa nada si el usuario selecciona que no.
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    }

    function editarTercero(indice) {
      $scope.terceroMostradoIndice = indice;
      copiarValoresTercero($scope.tercero[indice], $scope.terceroMostrado)
    }

    function eliminarTercero() {
      $ionicPopup.show({
        title: '¿Deseas eliminar al tercero ' + $scope.tercero[$scope.terceroMostradoIndice].nombre.toUpperCase() + ' con identificación ' + $scope.tercero[$scope.terceroMostradoIndice].identificacion.toUpperCase() + '?',
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Sí',
            onTap: function(e) {
              $scope.tercero.splice($scope.terceroMostradoIndice, 1);
              toastr.success('Tercero eliminado correctamente', 'Éxito');
              limpiarCampos();
            }
          },
          {
            text: '<b>No</b>',
            type: 'button-positive',
            onTap: function(e) {
              // No pasa nada si el usuario selecciona que no.
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    }

    function guardarTercero() {
      console.log('guardarTercero()');
      if (validarTercero()) {
        copiarValoresTercero($scope.terceroMostrado, $scope.tercero[$scope.terceroMostradoIndice]);
        limpiarCampos();
        toastr.success('Tercero guardado con éxito.', 'Éxito');
      }
    }

    function limpiarCampos() {
      copiarValoresTercero({}, $scope.terceroMostrado)
      $scope.terceroMostradoIndice = -1;
    }

    function validarTercero() {
      console.log('validarTercero()');
      var esValido = true;
      var camposLlenos = reclamoDetalleFactory.validarDatosTerceroIndividual($scope.terceroMostrado, vm.reclamo.idReclamo);

      if (!camposLlenos) {
        esValido = false;
        toastr.error('Llene los campos en rojo para continuar.', 'Información requerida');
      }

      var identificacionRepetida = false;

      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tercero.length; i++) {
        if ( (i != $scope.terceroMostradoIndice) && ($scope.terceroMostrado.identificacion == $scope.tercero[i].identificacion) ) {
          identificacionRepetida = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (identificacionRepetida) {
        esValido = false;
        toastr.error('Ya existe un tercero con la identificación especificada.', 'Identificación Duplicada');
      }

      return esValido;
    }

  }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT ------

We couldn't find a solution for the ghost click. It only happened on the android device (and not on the web version of the app). Therefore, we have decided to migrate the app to Android. Basically, we re-wrote the app for the Android platform. Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: use on-touch="vm.editarTercero($index)" instead of ng-click

Comment: We have tried on-touch and the ghost click persists.

Answer (score 0):

Does the problem occur on Windows Phone only or under IE? If yes, this is a known problem - see [$scope's method called via ng-click: executed twice by IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090543/scopes-method-called-via-ng-click-executed-twice-by-ie)

Comment: The ghost click happens on an Android device.

Comment: Please upload the sample to demonstrate the problem. For example here http://play.ionic.io/