# Checkbox inside label is not working as expected on IE11 browser using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using a toggle button for my application. For which I am using `label and checkbox(input)` combination. It is working fine for all the browsers expect IE(I am using IE 11). I have attached a click action to label instead of `input(checkbox)` due to some reasons in the past. If I click on the button then the event is occurring twice on IE browser. I already used stop propagation and also did put input tag outside the `label` tag but nothing is working.

```
<div class="col d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        <div class="form-check custom-form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label form-check-toggle float-right" ng-click="controller.activateToggle($event); $event.stopPropagation()">
                <input class="form-check-input"
                       ng-disabled="controller.myVariable ? false : true"
                       checked="{{controller.myVariable}}"
                       type="checkbox"
                       ng-model='controller.myVariable'
                       ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"
                />
                <span></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
 activateToggle(e) {
    if(this.myVariable){
       // opening a modal
    } else {
       // calling a function which opens a different modal
    }
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bhagyalaxmi28/gu0v5fzs/8/

But on IE browser clicking on toggle button both modals are getting opened where only one modal should get opened depending on the boolean value in if statement.

Comment: try with console.log(this.myVariable) and watch what you get on IE11 and what you need

Comment: @GiacomoM yes I did. On 1 click it is showing true and false both. But in other browsers it is showing just 1 value either true or false.

Comment: maybe is an angularjs issue. Try to search for it.

Comment: @GiacomoM tried to implement many solutions but nothing is working.

Comment: check if this post helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090543/scopes-method-called-via-ng-click-executed-twice-by-ie

Comment: @GiacomoM oh! i thought almost it saved me but unfortunately I am not using button tag :( I am using checkbox inside label. I really appreciate your effort in helping me.

Comment: maybe the problems are related. If your function is called once in any browser but IE (where it called twice), it should be an angularjs issue. The only thing you can do is search for known bugs in angularjs.